# Increase Speed of Wordle Bot (General For Any Programming Language)

Tags: performance, bots, wordle-game

I am working on a Wordle bot to calculate the best first (and subsequent) guess(es). I am assuming all 13,000 possible guesses are equally likely (for now), and I am running into a huge speed issue.

I can not think of a valid way to avoid a triple for loop, each with 13,000 elements. Obviously, this is ridiculously slow and would take about 20 hours on my laptop to compute the best first guess (I assume it would be faster for subsequent guesses due to fewer valid words).

The way I see it, I definitely need the first loop to test each word as a guess.
I need the second loop to find the colors/results given each possible answer with that guess.
Then, I need the third loop to see which guesses are valid given the guess and the colors.
Then, I find the average words remaining for each guess, and choose the one with the lowest average using a priority queue.

I think the first two loops are unavoidable, but maybe there's a way to get rid of the third?
Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing, for a list with 11,000 or so entries. It took 27 minutes.

I did it using a pregenerated (in one pass) list of the letters in a word,
as a bitfield (i.e. one 32 bit integer) and then did crude testing using
the AND instruction. if a word failed that, it exited the rest of the loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the response, what do you mean by crude testing using AND instruction? Also, do you mean you had a list of 11,000 bit fields and did one pass of this list in order to determine how many words would remain on average for this word?

Comment: Or is this a list of 11,000 identical bit fields, with each bit field being the same? Im trying to think through the solution